# Webpack: default file other than index.js

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader, es6-modules

In a current webpack project my code is partitioned into modules, each which has a main entry point with a `.module.js` ending. E.g. for the module `Util`, the entry point is `util.module.js` and I include it in other modules by writing `import util from 'modules/util/util.module.js'`

However, since all modules have the same syntax for the entry point, I would rather avoid specifying the full filename of the entry. E.g, it would be nice if I could just write `import util from 'modules/util'`.

I know this works if `util.module.js` is name `index.js`, but how can I tell Webpack to pick up my current module entries in the same way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll attempt to outline some readily available approaches, starting from your requirements and progressing towards something that's more conventional.

I sense that some overengineering of build tools might be creeping in, so I'd highly recommend you think again whether all of this is really necessary and reconsider the conventional approach.

It is analogous to how others would expect modules get to resolved, does not require Webpack and will not break other tools that internally attempt to resolve modules according to this strategy, like [eslint-plugin-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-import).

#### [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#normalmodulereplacementplugin)

Since you need to include the directory name in the module you're trying to resolve, you can use the `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin` to construct the resolve path dynamically:

```
new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(/modules\/(\w+)$/, (result) => {
    result.request += `/${result.request.split('/').pop()}.module.js`
}
```

You'd need to play around with this to ensure all valid names are covered.

#### [`resolve.extensions`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions)

If you really want to somehow distinguish these modules, then you could do so by providing a specific extension for them:

- `modules/util/index.module.js`
- `modules/dashboard/index.module.js`

It would be enough to configure:

```
{
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.module.js']
    }
}
```

#### Package main

Another approach would be to extract all your modules as packages, specifying `{main}` in [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main).

This will set you on a path towards a [monorepository](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/doc/design/monorepo.md).

#### Conventional

The conventional approach would be to name the modules `index.js`:

- `modules/util/index.js`
- `modules/dashboard/index.js`

Comment: This is a really complete answer! I'll admit, I've been searching for 2 days now for the initial approach described. My module files are named as `modules/[moduleName]/[moduleName].module.js` and so I thought I'd have to do some pattern matching to resolve correctly. After giving it some thought, renaming the files to `index.module.js` and adding `.module.js` to the `extensions` array is probably the perfect cross between code-searchability and convention. Thanks!